# dotnet build - Package References in .NET FW Build

Tags: .net, nuget

I'm stuck on some fundamental understanding of how to build a project outside of Visual Studio, using the dotnet.exe command line instead.  The project in question is a .NET Framework 4.7.2 console application, without the option of converting it to .NET Core.

I created a very simple console application that has exactly one package reference to a third party library that I pull in through Nuget.  Visual Studio understands that when it restores these packages, which it does by loading them into a /packages subdirectory, that it should look there for references when it builds.  dotnet.exe, however, is unaware of this, to the build fails with reference errors.  And I don't see an option where I can tell dotnet.exe to look in a certain place (/packages) for dependencies.

I believe my problem is more of a fundamental understanding of how to do everything via these command line tools and how to arrange things, so I'm not entirely sure what my actual problem is.

The entirety of "Program.cs" in my .NET FW Console application:

```
using JetBrains.Annotations;

namespace DotnetRestoreThisJawn
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main([NotNull] string[] args)
        {
        }       
    }
}
```

And the package reference within my .csproj:

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="JetBrains.Annotations">
      <Version>2018.3.0</Version>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

This is the nuget restore command I'm running, which I run at the solution directory level, and it then creates a /packages directory and restores the package as expected.  The packages directory is then a sibling to the console project directory.

`dotnet restore --no-cache -f --force-evaluate --interactive --packages packages`

And then the build command:

```
dotnet build --force
```

Which results in:

```
Program.cs(2,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'JetBrains' could not be found...
```

So, the error is clearly understandable, but I'm not sure how to get dotnet.exe to know where to find the dependency, or how I should restructure things so that I'm restoring the dependencies to the right place.

Comment: It should work, so you're not doing anything wrong. Looks like an environment issue on your machine. Try running `dotnet restore -v:n` to see if any errors are reported but hidden. It should say something about an assets file (obj/project.assets.json). Last resort is looking at the assets file to understand why `JetBrains.Annotations` isn't being used.

Answer (score 0):

For .NET 4.7.2 the dotnet CLI command "dotnet build" doesn't restore NuGet packages.

You have to use the command [dotnet restore](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-restore?tabs=netcore2x) before.

In the past in some cases it doesn't work for me.

I solved using the restore command of NuGet executable ([nuget.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/nuget/tools/nuget-exe-cli-reference)).

Comment: The .NET Core SDK 1.x didn't restore by default, but the 2.x cli/sdk does, even when the project targets the .NET Framework. Besides, the OP explicitly ran `dotnet restore` with a bunch of arguments.